# Novel about a trio of siblings in a war

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a specific novel series that I read years ago, and I'm wondering whether anyone here might be able to think of it.

Here's what I remember:

- The main protagonists were a set of 3 siblings, one girl and two boys. I feel like they were triplets as well, but I'm only about 85% sure. They were also important, but I can't remember if it was because of some kind of prophecy or if they were royalty.
- The word "bent" was used as a synonym for "homosexual".
- One of the brothers was not completely allied with the other two siblings and was morally dubious at times.
- There was some kind of war being fought as well.
- It was a medieval-type fantasy setting.

Comment: Please go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info. There are number of suggestions for questions to ask yourself about the book in question to elicit further details. Please read through that and add further revelations to your answer. Even negative answers ("I know it didn't have this" or "I know it's not *Shadows of Glass*) or uncertain answers ("It might have had some cats made of magnesium?") are useful.

Comment: Stupid question but are you sure you're not slightly mis-remembering [*The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lion,_the_Witch_and_the_Wardrobe)?

Comment: How many years ago is 'years ago'?

Comment: I would have read this before 2013

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158787/fantasy-book-series-perhaps-trilogy-with-elite-soldiers-flying-on-birds ?

Answer (score 3):

Could it be [The Emperor's Blades](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17910124-the-emperor-s-blades)?

> - The main protagonists were a set of 3 siblings, one girl and two boys. I feel like they were triplets as well, but I'm only about 85% sure. They were also important, but I can't remember if it was because of some kind of prophecy or if they were royalty.

> - The word "bent" was used as a synonym for "homosexual".

Not sure about this one.

> - One of the brothers was not completely allied with the other two siblings and was morally dubious at times.

In the third book Valyn isn't exactly helping the other two, and they don't share the same opinion of violence.

> - There was some kind of war being fought as well.

There is a war that the siblings must fight to defend their country.

> - It was a medieval-type fantasy setting.

This is set in medieval type times e.g. swords, shields, crossbows, and I think a little magic.

[Book on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FCQQCX6).

Comment: I've edited the post so it's clearer that the bullet points are quoted from the OP.